# PowerBI web: Disable 'Encrypt Connection'?

Tags: powerbi, amazon-redshift, powerbi-datasource

Is there any way to disable 'Encrypt Connection' in PowerBI for web?

This option does not seem to be available resulting in an error being thrown when trying to connect to AWS Redshift:

```
ODBC: ERROR [08S01] [Microsoft][Amazon Redshift] (10) Error occurred while trying to connect:[SQLState 08S01] host name must be specified for a verified SSL connection
```

There is no gateway being used.

Comment: Are you using the Amazon Redshift Connection in Power BI?

Comment: Yes for Desktop, where it is working as expected when "Enable Encryption" is disabled. When it is published to the PowerBI Service / Web and the credentials are added, it keeps failing. Upon some more research, it seems as if all PowerBI Service / web connections have encrypted connections that cannot be disabled (IE: a gateway is needed.) Do you know if this is a correct understanding?

Comment: I don't know to be honest - I used the Redshift ODBC Connector in the past to avoid this.

Comment: Thanks. I think the PowerBI Service may be forcing encrypted connections. We are using the ODBC connector in Desktop but no luck through the service.

Comment: I definitely used ODBC redshift with power bi gateway in the past - not sure about encryption though.

Comment: In your redshift parameter group enable SSL